# How to sort the adjecency matrix of bipartite graph so to have two off-diagonal blocks

Tags: matrix, graphs-and-networks, sorting

In a bipartite graphs there are two class of nodes, say A and B. Each node of class A may interact only with nodes of the class B, and viceversa. The corresponding adjecency matrix is thus composed by two off-diagonal blocks (if you sort the vertices in an appropriate way).

I realize that when working with adjecency matrix for a given bipartite graphs, sometimes I get the desired order in the adjecency matrix, and thus if I plot it, it is formed by two off-diagonal blocks:

```
g1=CompleteGraph[{5,3}]
m1=AdjacencyMatrix[g1] // MatrixPlot
```

[image: matrix plot of the bipartite graph]

However, sometimes if I plot the adjecency matrix directly from the bipartite graphs, now it is not in the desired order:

```
l2 = CompleteGraph[{5, 3}] // EdgeList;
weights = RandomReal[{0.5, 2}, Length[l2]];
g2 = Graph[l2, EdgeWeight -> weights, GraphLayout -> "BipartiteEmbedding"]
m2=AdjacencyMatrix[g2] // MatrixPlot
```

[image: matrix plot of the bipartite graph]

I'm trying to find a way to automatically sort m2 so to tranform it in a two off-diagonal blocks matrix.

Comment: Note that Dropbox links do not return images, but images embedded in HTML.  You need to upload the images to the SE host via the image button above the edit window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs on [AdjacencyMatrix](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/AdjacencyMatrix.html):

> Rows and columns of the adjacency matrix follow the order given by VertexList

And from the docs on [VertexList](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/VertexList.html):

> Vertices are taken in the order they appear in the list of edges.

Thus, you have

```
{VertexList[g1], VertexList[g2]}
(* {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, {1, 6, 7, 8, 2, 3, 4, 5}} *)
```

So, you can give an explicit list of vertices as the first argument of `Graph` to keep the adjacency matrix unchanged:

```
l2 = CompleteGraph[{5, 3}] // EdgeList;
v2 = CompleteGraph[{5, 3}] // VertexList;
weights = RandomReal[{0.5, 2}, Length[l2]];
g3 = Graph[v2, l2, EdgeWeight -> weights, GraphLayout -> "BipartiteEmbedding"]
m3 = AdjacencyMatrix[g3] // MatrixPlot
```

[image]

[image]

**Update:** Alternatively, you can re-arrange the rows and columns of `AdjacencyMatrix[g2]` ex post using `Ordering` as in @Wouter`s answer:

```
g2 = Graph[l2, EdgeWeight -> weights,  GraphLayout -> "BipartiteEmbedding"];
m2 = AdjacencyMatrix[g2];
m2b = m2[[Ordering[VertexList[g2]], Ordering[VertexList[g2]]]];
Row[ MatrixPlot[#, ImageSize -> 300] & /@ {m2, m2b}, Spacer[5]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM) has `IGBipartitePartitions` for identifying the two partitions.

With your example,

```
IGBipartitePartitions[g2]
(* {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8}} *)
```

Reorder the graph vertices:

```
g3 = IGReorderVertices[Flatten@IGBipartitePartitions[g2], g2];

MatrixPlot@AdjacencyMatrix[g3]
```

[image]

If you just want to visualize the adjacency matrix (with or without weights), but you do not need to compute with it, do both reordering and visualization in one step using `IGAdjacencyMatrixPlot`.

```
IGAdjacencyMatrixPlot[g2, Flatten@IGBipartitePartitions[g2]]
```

[image]

This function is quite flexible. Suppose you don't want to show weights and you don't want column labels rotated.

```
IGAdjacencyMatrixPlot[g2, Flatten@IGBipartitePartitions[g2], 
 EdgeWeight -> None, "RotateColumnLabels" -> False]
```

[image]

---

The following is a pure-Mathematica implementation of a function that splits a bipartite graph's vertices into two partitions.  The idea is that the partition that a vertex belongs to depends on whether its distance from some chosen vertex is odd or even.  If the graph is not connected, we need to split each component of the graph into partitions separately, then merge the results together.

```
singleComponentBipartitePartitions[graph_] :=
 GroupBy[
  Transpose@{VertexList[graph], Mod[GraphDistance[graph, First@VertexList[graph]], 2]},
  Last -> First
 ]

bipartitePartitions[graph_?BipartiteGraphQ] := 
  Module[{ug},
    (* First we convert the graph to undirected and make sure that 
       all edge weights are discarded so that they do not affect 
       the graph distance calculation—should ConnectedGraphComponents start
       preserving them in a future version. *)
    ug = Graph[VertexList[graph], EdgeList@UndirectedGraph[graph]];
    Values@Merge[
      singleComponentBipartitePartitions /@ ConnectedGraphComponents[ug], 
      Catenate
    ]
  ]

call : bipartitePartitions[expr_] := 
   (Message[bipartitePartitions::inv, HoldForm@OutputForm[call], OutputForm[expr], "bipartite graph"]; 
    $Failed)
```

Comment: You can get the groupings by `In[704]:= ConnectedComponents[AdjacencyGraph[1 - AdjacencyMatrix[g2]]]

Out[704]= {{1, 5, 6, 7, 8}, {2, 3, 4}}`.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau That works in this particular case, but it does not work for any bipartite graph.  Consider e.g. `CycleGraph[6]`, which is bipartite.   `AdjacencyGraph[1 - AdjacencyMatrix[g2]]` is (almost) the same as `GraphComplement[g2]`.

Comment: Ah. Okay, yes, this will fail in general.

Comment: @Daniel Maybe something like this for a pure-Mathematica implementation: `Merge[Function[g, 
   GroupBy[First@
     Last@Reap@
       BreadthFirstScan[g, First@VertexList[g], 
        "DiscoverVertex" -> (Sow[{Mod[#3, 2], #1}] &)],
    First -> Last]] /@ ConnectedGraphComponents[graph], Catenate]`

Comment: That should win a prize for something.

Comment: @Daniel I know it's terribly unreadable in one line, and with BreadthFirstSearch it was convoluted ... I edited the answer. Is it better now?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I am not writing these answers just to push the package. I really do believe that it is the best/simplest/fastest way to accomplish some tasks.  I wrote the package because I needed it.  Writing these answers also helps me better understand what people need and it helps me improve the package.

Comment: To be clear: I have no issue with the iGraph/M package*, the motivations for writing it, or use of it in MSE responses. I was commenting on that ornate, but probably very efficient, Mathematica snippet for reordering bipartite graph vertices. (Footnote in next comment)

Comment: * I do however hope that future development at WRI makes some of iGraph/M obsolete. It would be of benefit to those who use the product to have further support for graphs, networks, and related combinatorial functionality.

Comment: @Daniel Oh, I very much hope that it will be made obsolete!

Comment: I hd missed your question. Yes, the edited version is an improvement for readability. Now upvoted (I guess I forgot to do that several hours ago...)

Comment: @Daniel I certainly hope that a future Mathematica will make most of this obsolete ... but it seems to me that currently it is barely being developed. Most graph bugs I report are not getting fixed (to be fair, a few are, but the more serious ones aren't). Even fundamental infrastructure such as `VertexDelete` is broken (despite multiple bug reports), which is why I had to include functions like `IGWeightedVertexDelete` in the package ... E.g. `g = VertexDelete[
 Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3}, EdgeStyle -> {UndirectedEdge[2, 3] -> Blue}], 3]` creates a graph with a broken internal structure.

Comment: @Daniel It won't survive passing through a different representation (e.g. sending through MathLink or `Uncompress@Compress[g]`). Because of many problems like this Mathematica is next to unusable for practical "network science" stuff (perhaps the graph theory side is a bit better). It's a pity because there aren't many packages out there that would be as good as Mathematica if these minor but fundamental defects were fixed. I keep telling myself that perhaps the reason is that WRI is secretly working on a Graph 2.0 framework which would fix basic design problems ...

Comment: ... such as not being able to store edge properties in multigraphs (something that is sorely needed for practical work, unlike e.g. mixed graphs which just make implementation complicated for WRI without giving any practical benefit for users)

Answer (score 1):

maybe `Map[Part[#,Ordering[First[Normal[m2]]]]&,Normal[m2],{0,1}]` ?